# Deserializing json from stream gets null object

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

I have an example of json file
https://pastebin.com/wL6LWbxk

```
{
    "rates": [{
            "code": "ATS",
            "date": "2021-03-05",
            "date_from": "2021-03-05",
            "number": 40,
            "parity": 1,
            "exchange_middle": 8.5448
        }
    ]
}
```

and I have a following code:

```
...
var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(); //Im getting bytes OK
var something = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<Curr>(responseStream); //object something is null
...
```

My model looks like:

```
    public class Currency
    {
        [JsonProperty("code")]
        public string Code { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("date")]
        public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("date_from")]
        public DateTimeOffset DateFrom { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("number")]
        public long Number { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("parity")]
        public long Parity { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("exchange_middle")]
        public double ExchangeMiddle { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("exchange_buy", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public double? ExchangeBuy { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("exchange_sell", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public double? ExchangeSell { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("cash_buy", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public double? CashBuy { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("cash_sell", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public double? CashSell { get; set; }
    }

    public class Curr
    {
        [JsonProperty("rates")]
        public Currency[] Rates { get; set; }
    }
```

I done mapping model from json2csharp website.

I dont get it, why doesnt bind those properties. Thanks.

Comment: Is this System.Text.Json?

Comment: yes, it is System.Text.Json

Comment: Websites like json2csharp will assume you are using Newtonsoft JSON.Net so they won't work is you use `System.Text.Json`

Comment: Maybe the "conflict" is because Im using newtonsoft in my model annotations, and here in my businessLogic Im using system.text.json?

Comment: Yeah, don't do that.

Comment: so, instead of `[JsonProperty("date")]` I need to use `[JsonConverterAttribute("date")]` ?

Comment: If you replace your `JsonProperty` attributes (JSON.NET) with `JsonPropertyName` attributes (System.Text.Json), it should work. Note that VS has a built-in class generator for JSON, accessible via Edit | Paste Special | Paste JSON as Classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Websites like json2csharp will assume you are using Newtonsoft JSON.Net so they won't work is you use `System.Text.Json`.

You can fix your code by replacing the `JsonProperty` attributes with `JsonPropertyName` attributes. For example:

```
public class Curr
{
    [JsonPropertyName("rates")]
    public Currency[] Rates { get; set; }
}
```